# Magento simple product custom options price as product price

Tags: magento

I have product with price 0 and custom options (100g,200g,300g etc.) with prices 10$,20$...
In the product catalog and product page displays zero price, how to display cheapest option price? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you take the cheapest option (probably the 100g option) and enter its price as price for the product.

Then you define the **option price** as t the difference between the option price and the 100g price.

Example:
Apples, Price = 0.99$

Define the individual options as follows (pricetype: fixed)

- 100g: +0 $ [optional]
- 200g: +0.85$
- 300g: +1.60$

That way the cheapest price is shown in the product listing and the real price gets updated on product detail view page when the user selects the amount he wants to buy.